# Closing a message as a team representative

Tags: correspondence

I'm trying to find the expression to use when writing a message as a member of a team, as in:

> This is a reminder that all team members should act as team players.
>
> - John Smith, for the Tautological team

Is this "for the X team" construction correct? Could I write instead:

> For the Tautological team,
>
> John Smith

?

It's incredibly hard to search for this kind of expression, specifically when closing an e-mail, so I'm having a hard time finding usage examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one is fine, as long as it means what you intend. When someone says, "for the team", it is understood to mean that everyone on the team knows about and agrees with what you have written, and you are the one delivering the message.

If what you are writing does not represent everyone on your team, and you just want to say that you are part of that team, then omit "for the". For example, "John Smith, Tautological team"

Comment: My intention is indeed to convey the fact that everyone is aware of the message and I am just its bearer.

Answer (score 0):

I would just sign my name with my credentials, as below:

---

*This is a reminder that all team members should act as team players.*

```
    John Smith,  
    Team representative 
    Tautological team
```